# what is significance of "Mlocked" in /proc/meminfo file in Linux (CentOS)

Tags: linux, centos

I am using CentOs (2.6.32-279.el6.i686). I am not able to get details of use of "Mlocked" parameter in /proc/meminfo file. Can some one provide any details on this? In most of time, the value of this parameter is 0 KB.

Answer (score 0):

[mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) and related syscalls enable (privileged) programs to lock virtual memory segment into physical RAM. It is rarely used.

I guess the `Mlocked` line of `/proc/meminfo` is measuring this (probably system-wide cumulative). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)